# Why I got error when connects to mysql-workbench-community?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have installed mysql-workbench-community on my home ubuntu 22.04, but I
got error :

[image]

I use valid connections parameters - how can I fix this error ?

I have no problems with mysql or other apps access to mysql...